# Why is wire variable causing illegal left-hand side in continuous assignment?

Tags: verilog

I have read through all similar posts, but none address the issue I'm having, namely that line 41 `assign Y[b]=~Y[b];` causes error "Illegal left-hand side in continuous assignment."

I haven't assigned any regs so I don't see what the issue is. If I replace `b` with an actual number (say, 3) it works fine. But I need `b` as a variable here.

```
// Hamming code 1-bit error correction
module HCG(I,e,O);
  input [4:1] I;   // input BCD
  input [7:1] e;   // noise simulation
  wire [7:1] X;    // Hamming code
  wire [7:1] Y;     // Hamming code after addition of noise
  wire [3:1] P;     // Parity at start
  wire [3:1] S;    // Parity at end
  wire b;        // the error bit
  output [4:1] O;  // corrected output


  assign X[1]=I[1]^I[2]^I[4];   // Hamming code generator
  assign X[2]=I[1]^I[3]^I[4];
  assign X[3]=I[1];
  assign X[4]=I[2]^I[3]^I[4];
  assign X[5]=I[2];
  assign X[6]=I[3];
  assign X[7]=I[4];

  assign P[1]=X[1]; // Parity at start
  assign P[2]=X[2];
  assign P[3]=X[4];

  assign Y[1]=e[1]^X[1]; // noise added
  assign Y[2]=e[2]^X[2];
  assign Y[3]=e[3]^X[3];
  assign Y[4]=e[4]^X[4];
  assign Y[5]=e[5]^X[5];
  assign Y[6]=e[6]^X[6];
  assign Y[7]=e[7]^X[7];

  assign S[1]=Y[3]^Y[5]^Y[7]; // Parity at end
  assign S[2]=Y[3]^Y[6]^Y[7];
  assign S[3]=Y[5]^Y[6]^Y[7];

  assign b=(S[1]!=P[1])? b:b+1; // if parity of 2^0 not the same, add 1 to b
  assign b=(S[2]!=P[2])? b:b+2; // if parity of 2^1 not the same, add 2 to b
  assign b=(S[3]!=P[3])? b:b+4; // if parity of 2^2 not the same, add 4 to b

  assign Y[b]=~Y[b]; // correct the incorrect bit
  assign O[1]=Y[3]; // assigning outputs
  assign O[2]=Y[5];
  assign O[3]=Y[6];
  assign O[4]=Y[7];

endmodule
```

Answer (score 1):

The lines between `module` and `endmodule` are executed *concurently*. (It seems like you think they are executed sequentially.) Therefore, you are driving all the bits of `Y` in these lines

```
  assign Y[1]=e[1]^X[1]; // noise added
  assign Y[2]=e[2]^X[2];
  assign Y[3]=e[3]^X[3];
  assign Y[4]=e[4]^X[4];
  assign Y[5]=e[5]^X[5];
  assign Y[6]=e[6]^X[6];
  assign Y[7]=e[7]^X[7];
```

and then are driving one of the bits of `Y` again in this line:

```
  assign Y[b]=~Y[b]; // correct the incorrect bit
```

So (a) you have a short circuit and (b) which bit has the short circuit? That depends on `b`. So, the position of the short circuit depends on the state of one of the internal wires. You have described a circuit that can reconfigure itself depending on its inputs. Verilog won't let you do that. Verilog is a *hardware description language*. Conventional digital hardware can't reconfigure itself depending on the state of its inputs.

Comment: And `b` is only 1 bit wide. It can only ever by 0 or 1, never 3.

Comment: I have corrected my code, where do I post it again? Sorry I'm new to this forum.

Comment: @Joe if you have corrected your code and you now have a different error, then post a new question. If you do that, I would advise referring to this one to emphasise that you haven't asked the same question twice. However... You seem to have a fundamental misunderstanding of how Verilog works. Have you resolved that?

Comment: Well first of all I have made ```b``` an integer, placed it inside an ```always``` block, since I want its value to accumulate if each of the three conditions become true.

```always @(I,e)
  begin
    b=0; // initialize b to zero
  if(S[1]!=P[1])
    b=b+1;
  if(S[2]!=P[2])
    b=b+2;
  if(S[3]!=P[3])
    b=b+4;
  if(b!=0)
    begin
    Y[b]=!(Y[b]); // correct the incorrect bit
    end
  end
```

Comment: However, I'm still getting error, which I think is because I've placed ```Y``` which is a ```wire``` inside an ```always``` block. I'm having trouble understanding how to deal with reg and wire variables together under an if condition. I think you know what I want to achieve? Namely that if ```b is not equal to zero```, I want ```Y[b]``` to become ```!Y[b]```.

Comment: Well, if you still have a n error, I suggest a new question. But you can only assign variables (ie `reg`) from `always` blocks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the continuous assignment you are doing. To quote from the [IEEE Std 1800-2012.](http://www.ece.uah.edu/~gaede/cpe526/2012%20System%20Verilog%20Language%20Reference%20Manual.pdf) (Section 10.3) on continuous assignments:

> Continuous assignments shall drive values onto nets or variables, both vector (packed) and scalar. ***This assignment shall occur whenever the value of the right-hand side changes.*** Continuous assignments provide a way to model combinational logic without specifying an interconnection of gates.

When you do `assign Y[b]=~Y[b]`, the assignment itself automatically causes the right-hand side to change again, which triggers the assignment again.

Comment: I've tried correcting my code, where should I post it again?

Answer (score 0):

Verilog standard lists legal lhs values for the continuous assignment as the following (Table 10-1):

> Net or variable (vector or scalar)
>
> Constant bit-select of a vector net or packed variable
>
> Constant part-select of a vector net or packed variable
>
> Concatenation or nested concatenation of any of the above left-hand sides

in your case `Y[b]` is not a constant selection, because `b` is not a constant. Therefore syntactically your lhs is illegal and you get this message from the compiler.

On a side note you have a zero-delay loop here. See other answers for explanation.