# Verilog: How to deal with if conditions of wires?

Tags: verilog

Question follows over from here: [Why is wire variable causing illegal left-hand side in continuous assignment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56379459/why-is-wire-variable-causing-illegal-left-hand-side-in-continuous-assignment)

Below is my adjusted code, but I'm still having the problem of reconciling `b` (which is a reg) and `Y` (which is a wire) under the same `if` conditions. I get that a wire has to be viewed as a result of the combinations its attached to, and can't just be assigned a value, and certainly not as a function of itself. And all the stuff about not being allowed to use `assign` to regs or that wires can't be used in `if` blocks.

But the problem is once `b` is calculated, and if `b!=0`, how do I correct the *b*th bit error (`Y[b]`) and getting it to flip from 1 to 0 or vice versa?

```
// Hamming code 1-bit error correction
module HCG(I,e,O);
  input [4:1] I;   // input BCD
  input [7:1] e;   // noise simulation
  wire [7:1] X;    // Hamming code
  wire [7:1] Y;     // Hamming code after addition of noise
  wire [3:1] P;     // Parity at start
  wire [3:1] S;    // Parity at end
  integer b;       // the error bit    
  output [4:1] O;  // corrected output

  assign X[1]=I[1]^I[2]^I[4];   // Hamming code generator
  assign X[2]=I[1]^I[3]^I[4];
  assign X[3]=I[1];
  assign X[4]=I[2]^I[3]^I[4];
  assign X[5]=I[2];
  assign X[6]=I[3];
  assign X[7]=I[4];

  assign P[1]=X[1]; // Parity at start
  assign P[2]=X[2];
  assign P[3]=X[4];

  assign Y[1]=e[1]^X[1]; // noise added
  assign Y[2]=e[2]^X[2];
  assign Y[3]=e[3]^X[3];
  assign Y[4]=e[4]^X[4];
  assign Y[5]=e[5]^X[5];
  assign Y[6]=e[6]^X[6];
  assign Y[7]=e[7]^X[7];

  assign S[1]=Y[3]^Y[5]^Y[7]; // Parity at end
  assign S[2]=Y[3]^Y[6]^Y[7];
  assign S[3]=Y[5]^Y[6]^Y[7];

  always @(I,e)
  begin
    b=0; // initialize b to zero
  if(S[1]!=P[1])
    b=b+1;
  if(S[2]!=P[2]) // b is cumulative if each of the conditions is true
    b=b+2;
  if(S[3]!=P[3])
    b=b+4;
  if(b!=0)
    begin
    Y[b]=!(Y[b]); // HOW TO CORRECT THIS?
    end
  end

  assign O[1]=Y[3]; // assigning outputs
  assign O[2]=Y[5];
  assign O[3]=Y[6];
  assign O[4]=Y[7];

endmodule
```

Comment: You have more problems: `always @(I,e)` uses P and Y but those are not in the sensitivity list. Use `always @( *)` or `always_comb`. The biggest danger is that your simulation might make you think it works,  but your synthesized code does not. In general: your are still programming HDL like it is a standard (c/python etc.) language. Start thinking in operation (gates) connected by wires.

Comment: I see. Yeah I've only just started on Verilog. I'm still getting an error due to the line ```Y[b]=!(Y[b]); // HOW TO CORRECT THIS?```. I know why it's wrong but I still have no clue how to correct it! Do I have to create two modules or something for this to work?

Comment: You have not addressed your fundamental misunderstanding of how Verilog works. You're not writing software, you're designing hardware. I think you need to ask yourself this question: "what hardware am I expecting?" Whenever you write code in an HDL you need to be able to answer that question. By this, I mean you should be able to draw a block diagram of your design, easily, without really thinking about it (because you should have already drawn that block diagram, either actually or in your head)...

Comment: ...So, you should be able to draw a block diagram that has counters, FSMs, memories, shift-registers, clouds of random combinational logic, muxes, perhaps some flip-flops etc etc

Answer (score 1):

As I said in the comments: your code is very ... sub-optimal. So here I'll answer only:

> Y[b]=!(Y[b]); // HOW TO CORRECT THIS?

If you write Y[b]=!(Y[b]) (and there is no clock involved) you have made a combinatorial loop: Y[b] becomes not Y[b], which immediately becomes not-not Y[b], which immediately becomes not-not-not Y[b] etc.

You have to use forward working logic: make a new variable e.g. Z which is equal to Y but bit b (b!=0) is inverted.

```
always @( * )
   case (b)
   1 : Z = Y ^ 4'b0010;
   2 : Z = Y ^ 4'b0100;
   3 : Z = Y ^ 4'b1000;
   default : Z = Y;
   endcase
```

(Of course it also helps if you are familiar with how the various logic operations work.)

<sub>Not tested, typos are possible</sub>

Answer (score 0):

So my problem was that I was trying to change `Y` when it really couldn't be changed (unless the inputs or wires that defined it changed). I fixed the problem by making a new variable `reg z` to take on the values of `Y` and then have `Z`'s *b*th-bit be flipped instead.

```
module HCG(I,e,O);
  input [4:1] I;   // input BCD
  input [7:1] e;   // noise simulation
  wire [7:1] X;    // Hamming code
  wire [7:1] Y;     // Hamming code after addition of noise
  wire [3:1] P;     // Parity at start
  wire [3:1] S;    // Parity at end
  integer b;       // the error bit
  reg [7:1] Z;     // corrected hamming code
  output [4:1] O;  // corrected output

  assign X[1]=I[1]^I[2]^I[4];   // Hamming code generator
  assign X[2]=I[1]^I[3]^I[4];
  assign X[3]=I[1];
  assign X[4]=I[2]^I[3]^I[4];
  assign X[5]=I[2];
  assign X[6]=I[3];
  assign X[7]=I[4];

  assign P[1]=X[1]; // Parity at start
  assign P[2]=X[2];
  assign P[3]=X[4];

  assign Y[1]=e[1]^X[1]; // noise added
  assign Y[2]=e[2]^X[2];
  assign Y[3]=e[3]^X[3];
  assign Y[4]=e[4]^X[4];
  assign Y[5]=e[5]^X[5];
  assign Y[6]=e[6]^X[6];
  assign Y[7]=e[7]^X[7];

  assign S[1]=Y[3]^Y[5]^Y[7]; // Parity at end
  assign S[2]=Y[3]^Y[6]^Y[7];
  assign S[3]=Y[5]^Y[6]^Y[7];

  always @( *)
  begin
    b=0; // initialize b to zero
    Z=Y; // initialize Z1~Z7 with Y1~Y1
  if(S[1]!=P[1])
    b=b+1;
  if(S[2]!=P[2]) // b is cumulative if each of the conditions is true
    b=b+2;
  if(S[3]!=P[3])
    b=b+4;
  if(b!=0)
    Z[b]=~(Y[b]); // correct the incorrect b'th-bit
  end

  assign O[1]=Z[3]; // assigning outputs
  assign O[2]=Z[5];
  assign O[3]=Z[6];
  assign O[4]=Z[7];

endmodule
```